# magento 2 setup:static-content:deploy execution time error

Tags: magento2, cli

I am trying to install quick setup of theme also did but css and js is not loading so i run command.
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
but every time getting error like execution time
is there any solution?

Comment: Could you please brief more in detail?

Comment: whenever i try to run command setup:static-content:deploy i am getting error for execution time after some running

Comment: Could you please post that exception here?